# How to use GROUP_CONCAT with Zend Framework 3?

Tags: sql, zend-framework3

Assume that I have a table : organization_branches_custom_not_working_days

```
_________________________________________________________________________
|id   | created_at             | date        | organization_branch_id    |
_________________________________________________________________________
| 1   | 2020-03-01 21:42:05    | 2020-02-28  | 2                         |
| 2   | 2020-03-01 21:42:05    | 2020-02-28  | 2                         |
| 3   | 2020-03-01 21:42:05    | 2020-02-28  | 2                         |                  
| 4   | 2020-03-01 21:42:05    | 2020-02-28  | 1                         |
__________________________________________________________________________
```

Using this query :

```
SELECT organization_branch_id, GROUP_CONCAT(date SEPARATOR ', ') FROM organization_branches_custom_not_working_days GROUP BY organization_branch_id;
```

Comment: Could you please add a few details to the question? Like, what did you already tried, what's your starting code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must `use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression` like

```
$select->columns(organization_branch_id, new Expression("GROUP_CONCAT(date SEPARATOR ', ')"));
```